# ../../third_party/dart/runtime/vm/object.cc: 2329: error: Out of memory

Tags: flutter, dart

Build fingerprint:

> 'google/sdk_gphone_x86/generic_x86:10/QSR1.191030.002/5978551:userdebug/dev-keys'
>   Revision: '0'
>   ABI: 'x86'
>   Timestamp: 2020-03-09 17:44:16+0530
>   pid: 22638, tid: 22905, name: Thread-2

I am getting this error while debugging the app. Worked Fine in release mode.

Comment: did you find out something? What work are you doing while debugging? For me it occurs when i quickly switch the bottom navigation tabs..

Comment: @AlessandroSantamaria I am not able to predict that when it occurs sometimes while opening the app it will cause the error.